# Adding and subtracting values based off year conditions Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I've got two dataframes that both have **Dates**. The dataframe has repeated dates for every **Type** and every **State** because it's a cumulative summed frame which looks like:

```
Date          State     Type      Value
2010-01-01    AK        NUC       10
2010-02-01    AK        NUC       10
2010-03-01    AK        NUC       10
.
.
2010-01-01    CO        NUC       2
2010-02-01    CO        NUC       2
.
.
2010-01-01    AK        WND       20
2010-02-01    AK        WND       21
.
.
2018-08-01   .......
```

What I need to do is take the second dataframe and **add** based off the **'Operating Date'**, to each **'Type'** and **'State'** and then **subtract** based off the **'Retirement Date'** all with respect to the original **'Date'**. The second dataframe looks like:

```
Operating Date   Retirement Date   Type    State       Value
2010-02-01       2010-04-01        NUC     AK          1
2011-02-01       2014-02-01        NUC     AK          2
2011-03-01       2016-03-01        NUC     AK          10
.
.

.
2018-08-01   .......
```

For example on **AK** the output would add and subtract like:

```
if AK(Date) == AK(Operating Date):
      AK(Value, Date) = AK(Value, Date) + AK(Value, Operating Date)

elif AK(Date) == AK(Retirement Date):
      AK(Value, Date) = AK(Value, Date) - AK(Value, Retirement Date)
else:
      continue
```

And the actual output dataframe (just for AK 'NUC') would be:

```
Date          State     Type      Value
2010-01-01    AK        NUC       10
2010-02-01    AK        NUC       11
2010-03-01    AK        NUC       11
2010-04-01    AK        NUC       10
.
.
2011-01-01    AK        NUC       10
2011-02-01    AK        NUC       12
2011-03-01    AK        NUC       22
2011-04-01    AK        NUC       22
.
.
2016-01-01    AK        NUC       22
2010-02-01    AK        NUC       22
2010-03-01    AK        NUC       12
2010-04-01    AK        NUC       12
.
.
```

How can I go about doing this type of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main DataFrame used in code below

```
df

Date        State   Type    Value
2010-01-01  AK      NUC     10
2010-02-01  AK      NUC     10
2010-03-01  AK      NUC     10
2010-01-01  CO      NUC     2
2010-02-01  CO      NUC     2
2010-01-01  AK      WND     20
2010-02-01  AK      WND     21
```

The changes you want to add to the main, note that I replaced space with _

```
delta

Operating_Date  Retirement_Date Type    State   Value
2010-02-01      2010-04-01      NUC     AK      1
2011-02-01      2014-02-01      NUC     AK      2
2011-03-01      2016-03-01      NUC     AK      10
```

The plan of attack is to use one date column, in order to do this we need to combine retirement date and operating date into one column, we give the value a negative number when we use retirement date and keep the positive value for the operating date

```
#We first make a copy of the delta, we will call these cancellations and use the 
#Retirement_Date and the value in negative
cx = delta.copy()
cx['Date']=cx['Retirement_Date']
cx.drop(['Operating_Date','Retirement_Date'],axis=1,inplace=True)
cx['Value'] *=-1

#In the original delta we assign operating date as the date value
delta['Date'] = delta['Operating_Date']
delta.drop(['Operating_Date','Retirement_Date'],axis=1,inplace=True)

#We then append the cancellations to the main delta frame and rename the values 
#column to delta
delta = delta.append(cx)
delta.rename(columns={'Value':'Delta'},inplace=True)
```

We now have a dataframe with one date column containing all positive and negative changes we want to track per date

```
delta

Type    State   Delta   Date
NUC     AK      1       2010-02-01
NUC     AK      2       2011-02-01
NUC     AK      10      2011-03-01
NUC     AK      -1      2010-04-01
NUC     AK      -2      2014-02-01
NUC     AK      -10     2016-03-01
```

Now all we need to do is to add the cumulative value of the changes to the main dataframe

```
#we start by merging the data frames, as the column names are the same and we want to merge on all of them we just specify that it's an outer join
df = df.merge(delta,how='outer')
#if there are any new dates in the delta that aren't in the main dataframe we want to bring forth our cumulative sum
#but first we need to make sure we sort by date so the cumulative sum works
df.sort_values(['Type','State','Date'],inplace=True)

df['Value'] = df.groupby(['State','Type'])['Value'].ffill()

#for the dates where we have no changes we fill with zeros
df['Delta'].fillna(0,inplace=True)

#we can now add the cumilative sum of the delta to the values column

df['Value'] +=df.groupby(['State','Type'])['Delta'].cumsum().astype(int)

#and lastly we can remove the delta column again and we're done
del df['Delta']
```

the final dataframe, which hopefully is what you're after

```
df

Date        State   Type    Value
2010-01-01  AK      NUC     10
2010-02-01  AK      NUC     11
2010-03-01  AK      NUC     11
2010-04-01  AK      NUC     10
2011-02-01  AK      NUC     12
2011-03-01  AK      NUC     22
2014-02-01  AK      NUC     20
2016-03-01  AK      NUC     10
2010-01-01  CO      NUC     2
2010-02-01  CO      NUC     2
2010-01-01  AK      WND     20
2010-02-01  AK      WND     21
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed response. Not only solved the issue but with great commenting. A++ :)